# Write KML Extended Data in a different way

Tags: gps, kml, raw-data

I have some GPS raw data that I want to put on a KML file.

Currently I can generate the KML file with the Extended Data using the KML format described here https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#trackexample and that's fine, but it takes too much time.

I am collecting six different types of extended data, using an Arduino and writing them on a SD card, but the entire writing process for each sample is too slow (I write the data on six different files and then I append each file to the final KML, using the gx:track element).

Is there any other way to write all six parameters at the same time, in the KML format using the Extended Data ? maybe using different tags or same tags in different order?

I don't have enough cpu power to rework the file after collecting gps raw data, so I need to write it right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

write the kml totally yourself, do not use an library. Then it is as fast as simply writing text to a file. if the bottleneck is the file system, then kml is not the right format. Use a custom binary file, and transform later to kml on server side.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. I have already implemented your solution (binary file saved on the sd card and client sw on the pc that creates the KML) but I would like to generate the file on the Arduino platform, without using a client software on the PC. My need is to have only Arduino as a logger and Google Earth as a viewer. I tried to remix the XML tags of the KML in order to have them grouped not by type (all date&time, all coordinates, ...) but by "time" (all parameters red at the same time) but I am not a KML/XML expert and the result file doesn't work. Thanks, FP

Comment: kml is not suitable for GPS logging, in logging you need a timestamp, lat, long, etc. in kml usually there is only lat, lon, altitude